# promedio de calificaciones por semestre

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Quiero calcular el promedio de 8 semestres de 5 calificaciones cada uno, ya tengo un codigo que me suma el promedio de cada semestre por separado correctamente pero ya no se como sumar el promedio todos juntos para sacar un promedio general.

```
Algoritmo kardex
    Definir semestre Como Entero    
    numSem <- 8
    Dimension  semestre[numSem]
    numNotas <- 5
    Dimension notas[numNotas]

    Para x <-1 hasta numSem con paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Notas del semestre ", x
        Para i<-1 Hasta numNotas Con Paso 1 Hacer
            
            Escribir "Ingrese el valor de la nota ", i
            Leer notas[i]
        Fin Para
        
        promedio= (notas[1]+notas[2]+notas[3]+notas[4]+notas[5]) / 5
        
        Si promedio > 7.9 Entonces
            Escribir "Promedio aprobatorio del semestre ",x " es de " promedio
        SiNo
            Escribir "Promedio reprobatorio del semeste ", x " es de " promedio
        Fin Si
    FinPara
    
    promediogral="?"
    Escribir "El promedio general es " promediogral
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Si te entendí bien y ya tienes la suma de los promedios de los 8 meses solo tienes que dividir el resultado por 8.

Comment: @Mateo no lo que pasa es que no se como hacer la suma de cada promedio

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El promedio puedes calcularlo así también:

```
promedio = 0
Para i<-1 Hasta numNotas Hacer
    promedio = promedio + notas[i]
Fin Para
promedio = promedio / numNotas
```

Para el promedio general puedes algo parecido:

```
Para x <-1 Hasta numSem Hacer
    ...
    semestre[x] = promedio
FinPara

promedioGeneral = 0
Para i <- 1 Hasta numSem Hacer
    promedioGeneral = promedioGeneral + semestre[i]
Fin Para
promedioGeneral = promedioGeneral / numSem
```